# Sorting an array of integers using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to write a program that sorts an array (input by user) using pointers.
This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[100],i,n,j,t;
    printf("Enter number of elements:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter array:\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",a+i);
    }
    for (i=0; i<(n-1); i++)
    {
        for (j=i+1; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (*(a+i)>*(a+j))
            {
                t=*(a+i);
                *(a+i)=*(a+j);
                *(a+j)=t;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Sorted array (ascending) is:\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*(a+i));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The compiler is not showing any errors.

Input:
5
1 5 4 2 8
Output:
1 8 4 2 5

I'm learning by myself and I got the idea that pointers are similar to arrays. I know how to do the same task with arrays but when I try here to substitute them with pointers it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are increasing i in both for loops; you should increase j instead of i;

Comment: Hint: you can derefernce pointers by using`[]`. (and main() should return int, not void.)

Comment: @PatrickTrentin fixed it and now it just crashed

Comment: You should also check for j < n instead of i < n

Comment: Trying to use pointers when there were none, only obfuscates the code. Stick to the clear array syntax. `*(a+i)=*(a+j);` is better as `a[i] = a[j];` Even if the code was in a function, where the array passed decays to a pointer, it is still clearer the way I suggest.

Comment: Should I delete the question, since I see the mistake is pretty stupid (basically a typo)? I can't believe I missed it.

Comment: @Plexus I answered in the comments exactly for allowing you to do that since it was evidently a very minor error,
 [but that's no longer possible (for you, at least) because there are positive-scored answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that?noredirect=1&lq=1). Instead, you might want to revert your own edit fixing part of the question, since both answers quote the original source code and that might be confusing.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin yeah I figured that out, but everything was happening so fast, 2 answers came in like a couple of minutes after it, there were comments as well and I was also trying the program, so I didn't quite manage to do everything in time

Comment: That's fine, and welcome on StackOverflow (:

Comment: @wildplasser I understood that main() is a function and can be void or int. Correct me if I'm wrong, that if int function has return 0, that it's the same as void?

Comment: `main()` is indeed a function. It should return int, basically because its caller expects it to return int. (and the caller is not under our control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in your second loop while you are sorting:

```
for (i=0; i<(n-1); i++)
    {
        for (j=i+1; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (*(a+i)>*(a+j))
            {
                t=*(a+i);
                *(a+i)=*(a+j);
                *(a+j)=t;
            }
        }
    }
```

you need to change the counter names to `j` :

```
for (i=0; i<(n-1); i++)
    {
        for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            if (*(a+i)>*(a+j))
            {
                t=*(a+i);
                *(a+i)=*(a+j);
                *(a+j)=t;
            }
        }
    }
```

this line has the problem :

```
for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
```

Comment: it is always a possible danger for every programmer :D if you find my answer true, mark it as true answer

Comment: Thanks, it is true, but now I'm so embarrassed for asking it

Comment: be proud of yourself, someone who scare of asking question have to be embarrased,not you , good luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because your `j` variable is not increased properly and wrong comparison is used (as suggested by Patrick). I think it should be as follow:

```
for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
```